# The data from an HTML form is not being passed to MySQL using Flask (Python)

Tags: python, mysql, flask, sqlalchemy, pythonanywhere

I need some help here, please. I just can't get this code to insert data from an HTML form into MySQL. The rows are always inserted without any data. Completely empty. Let me know your thoughts!

PS: MySql has 2 more fields, which I am not using yet and these files are all hosted on PythonAnywhere.

## HTML (Only the form):

```
<form action="{{ url_for('register_user') }}" method="post">
    <div class="register-form">

        <input type="text" class="register-field" id="firstname" value="" placeholder="First name" name="firstname">
        <label class="register-field-icon fui-user" for="register-name"></label>

        <input type="text" class="register-field" id="lastname" value="" placeholder="Last name" name="lastname">
        <label class="register-field-icon fui-user" for="register-name"></label>

        <input type="text" class="register-field" id="email" value="" placeholder="Email" name="email">
        <label class="register-field-icon fui-user" for="register-name"></label>

        <input type="password" class="register-field" id="password" value="" placeholder="Password" name="password">
        <label class="register-field-icon fui-lock" for="register-pass"></label>

        <label class="register-field-icon fui-lock" for="register-pass"></label>
        <input type="submit" value="Register" id="register-btn" class="btn register-btn">

    </div>
</form>
```

## FLASK (without the connection details for MySql):

```
from datetime import datetime
from flask import Flask, redirect, render_template, request, url_for, session
from flask_login import current_user, login_required, login_user, LoginManager, logout_user, UserMixin
from flask_migrate import Migrate
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from werkzeug.security import check_password_hash
from flask import session as login_session


@app.route("/register/", methods=["GET", "POST"])
    def register_user():
    if request.method == "GET":
        return render_template("register.html")

    else:

        User_Data = Reg_User(firstname=request.form["firstname"],lastname=request.form["lastname"],email=request.form["email"],password_hash=request.form["password"])#,groups="freeuser")
        db.session.add(User_Data)
        db.session.commit()

        return redirect(url_for('login'))



class Reg_User(db.Model):

    __tablename__ = 'users'

    def __init__(self, firstname, lastname, email, password_hash):#, groups):

        id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
        firstname = db.Column(db.String(20), unique=False, nullable=False)
        lastname = db.Column(db.String(45), unique=False, nullable=False)
        email = db.Column(db.String(45), unique=True, nullable=False)
        password_hash = db.Column(db.String(128), unique=False, nullable=False)


    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Reg_User %r>'.format(self.username)
```

## MYSQL:

```
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------

|  id  |  username  |  password_hash  |  firstname  |  lastname  |  email  |   groups  |  regtime  |

+--------------------------------------------------------------------------

|  43  |     NULL     |          NULL           |     NULL      |     NULL     |  NULL  |   NULL   |  2019-01-09 22:00:56 |

|  44  |     NULL     |          NULL           |     NULL      |     NULL     |  NULL  |   NULL   |  2019-01-09 22:55:09 |

|  45  |     NULL     |          NULL           |     NULL      |     NULL     |  NULL  |   NULL   |  2019-01-09 23:04:15 |

|  46  |     NULL     |          NULL           |     NULL      |     NULL     |  NULL  |   NULL   |  2019-01-09 23:10:32 |
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are creating and using your model class incorrectly.

You don't actually need `__init__` at all in your case. Also, you are doing some incorrect things in your constructor, a short refresher tutorial on Python classes wouldn't hurt here.

**Here is a User model pattern you can follow**

You do not need to define `__init__`

```
class User(db.Model):
    """Users"""

    __tablename__ = 'users'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    first_name = db.Column(db.String(25), nullable=False)
    last_name = db.Column(db.String(25), nullable=False)
    image_url = db.Column(db.Text, default=DEFAULT_IMG_URL)
    email = db.Column(db.String(45), unique=True, nullable=False)
    password = db.Column(db.String(128), unique=False, nullable=False)

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'<User id:{self.id} first_name:{self.first_name} last_name:{self.last_name} image_url:%.8s' % self.image_url

    def get_full_name(self):
        return f'{self.first_name} = {self.last_name}'
```

**You can create a new user by creating an instance of the model then committing to the database**

```
@app.route("/register/", methods=["GET", "POST"])
    def register_user():
    if request.method == "GET":
        return render_template("register.html")

    else:
        first_name = request.form.get('first_name')
        last_name = request.form.get('last_name') 
        email = request.form.get('email')
        password = request.form.get('password')

        # hash your password, this is a separate topic
        hashed = bcrypt.generate_password_hash(password).decode('utf-8')

        user = User(first_name=first_name, last_name=last_name, email=email, password=hashed)

        db.session.add(user)
        db.session.commit()

        return redirect(url_for('login'))
```

Comment: Perfect. Thank you. I just had to add "__table_args__ = {'extend_existing': True}", because of another class (login) not pasted in this question. Helped a lot!